# Returning existing field words using ArcGIS field calculator

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, arcgis-10.3, python-parser

I need to write a script. The image below shows the data that I am working with. I would like to add the data from the field `Frost_Corr` for the remaining fields in `SubTrp_Cor`. For example where it reads "low frost risk" is in `SubTrp_Cor`, I would like the rows above to read as "High frost risk" and the row below to read as "low frost risk"(thus match Frost_corr).

Below is the script that I created for the field SubTrp_Cor. I am aware that currently I am returning a blank if the conditions are not met.  However, I am not sure which function needs to be used to return whats in the field Frost_Corr if the conditions are not met.

```
def calc (TEMP_ZONE , Frost_Corr):
     if TEMP_ZONE =="Sub-tropical" and Frost_Corr=="Moderate frost risk":
         return "Low frost risk"
     elif TEMP_ZONE =="Sub-tropical" and Frost_Corr== "High frost risk":
         return "Low frost risk"
     else:
         return ""
```

Comment: If you want to just copy why do you need a script, you can just copy using the field calculator? and change the only row with "low frost risk". And if you want to automate search and update cursor has to be used.

Comment: There are other many other rows under SubTrp_Cor that have the words "Low frost risk'', hence thought a script would be needed. Basically I would like to know in the SubTrp_Cor script what needs to be said that if the conditions are not met, then print what's in the Frost_Corr field.

Comment: It is a little bit unclear what you want. For the field with 'Low frost risk' in the rightmost field it says 'Moderate..' in `Frost Corr`, why?

Comment: The field Frost_Corr have been calculated based on several other fields and different thresholds. Thereafter SubTrp_Cor was calculated based on Frost_Corr and another variable .  Hence, if the criteria of that variable was met, then a change in Frost_Corr is indicated and stated in SubTrp_Cor. While the remainder of rows need to return the statements in Frost_Corr. I hope it makes sense

Comment: There are two ways to accomplish this. The first is to learn enough Python coding to accomplish what you want in a custom Calculate Field script. The other is to use attribute selection and a constant value for the various combinations. Now, if there are tens of millions of rows involved, with dozens of combinations, then learning Python is a necessity. Otherwise, it's going to be faster to  just calculate what you need. Either way, GIS SE isn't likely to just do your task for you without any effort on your part.

Comment: Hi there, Apologies for not including the script that I created.

Comment: Aaah! Thank you Bera. That was so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return the value of Frost_Corr if the if/elifs are not met simply do:

```
def calc (TEMP_ZONE , Frost_Corr):
     if TEMP_ZONE =="Sub-tropical" and Frost_Corr=="Moderate frost risk":
         return "Low frost risk"
     elif TEMP_ZONE =="Sub-tropical" and Frost_Corr== "High frost risk":
         return "Low frost risk"
     else:
         return Frost_Corr
```